Count how often an element in a list of dicts is unequal to "X"
I have list of dicts.
Each dict has the same items with a different value. It is a question code with the answer.
So question "a" can be answerd with a scale of 1-7. If you do not want to answer that question, it is an "X" in the answer sheet.
example:
[
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":"X"},
{"a":1,"b":"X","c":3},
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":"X"}
]

My goal is to know, if there is any question, that has less than 5 or more than 50 valid answers. A valid answer is anything except "X".
So I need to count now, how often any item is not equal "X".
In that case, for "a" it would be 3, for "b" it would be 2 and for "c" it would be 1.
I could loop through it.
Make an array for each item in the dicts. Then loop trough the list, inside that loop through the dict and add +1 to the item in the array. Afterwards check the counter, if there is any item < 5 or > 50.
But there is probably some sweet python code (as always) that does this in like 3 lines. While my loop would probably be 5 times bigger.
And is faster. I have to repeat that check a few thousand times. So speed is kinda important. Not super duper important, but nice to have

Do all the dictionaries in the list have the same keys? Said differently is it enough the read the first dictionary to know all the possible keys?

Yes. All keys are the same. And I have all keys hardcoded in an array. They dont change.

Do you care only if there is any? Do you want to know which one? Do you want all of them between 5 and 50?

I only care if there is one entry below 5 or over 50. I dont need to know which one. I dont need to know if one, two, or more are below 5 too.
It is enough to get a true/false for the question: is there any question under 5 or over 50.

As everything is loaded in memory, I would just iterate the keys, counting the number of 'X' per key. Assuming your list of dictionary is ld I would try:
keys = ld[0].keys()    # ignore this if you already have a list of the keys
missing = {k: sum(d[k] == 'X' for d in ld) for k in keys}

With your sample data, it returns - as expected:
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}

Of course this only makes sense if no dictionary after the first one contains a new key...

Note sure why it was voted down, but it is a nice solution. I just changed it to != "X" so its easier to check for <5. Thanks!

There are several solutions.  You can use the collection.Counter and iterate through the items in your list, checking if the value is 'X'.
from collections import Counter

data = [
    {"a":1,"b":2,"c":"X"},
    {"a":1,"b":"X","c":3},
    {"a":1,"b":2,"c":"X"}
]
counts = Counter(k for d in data for k, v in d.items() if v=='X')

for k, v in sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda tup: tup[1]):
    if v < 5:
        print(f'{k} has less than 5 "X" responses ({v})')
    if v > 50:
        print(f'{k} has greater than 50 "X" responses ({v})')

If you want a sledgehammer, you could use pandas and load the data into a data frame and then sum when values are equal to 'X'
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
counts = df.ne('X').sum(axis=0).sort_values()
print('Keys with less than 5 "X" responses:')
print('\n'.join(repr(counts[counts.lt(5)]).split('\n')[:-1]))
print('Keys with more than 50 "X" responses:')
print('\n'.join(repr(counts[counts.gt(50)]).split('\n')[:-1]))


You are missing brace bracket.
print(f'{k} has less than 5 "X" responses ({v})')
     


 print(f'{k} has greater than 50 "X" responses ({v})')

